# cout<<(5<<3)<<endl;

Tags: c++

Почему при выводе:
   `cout<<(5<<3);` 
На экран выводится 40.

Comment: Потому что скобки - приоритет.

Comment: А что должно выводиться? Откуда вообще возник вопрос?

Comment: Да в тестах где-то увидел, такой код. Учусь по Дейтелу, и в книге особо ответа на этот вопрос не нашел, прошерстил интернет, понял, что операторы << и >> побитовое смещение соответственно влево и вправо, но так и не понял, почему результат 40. Просто хочется более подробно вникнуть в язык с++ и его операторы, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Потому, что эта запись означает.

1) Сдвинуть двоичную запись числа 5 на три разряда влево.

2) Вывести результат на экран

Двоичная запись числа 5, это 101
Сдвигаем влево на три разряда 101000 = 40

Answer (score 5):

В языке C++ встроенная операция сдвига влево `E1 << E2` для беззнаковых целых типов и положительных значений знаковых целых типов *определяется* через операцию умножения сдвигаемого значения на 2<sup>E2</sup>, Таким образом `5 << 3` по определению равно `5 * 8`, то есть `40`.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `<<` — это всего лишь функция с именем `operator<<`, которую можно перегружать как угодно и с какими угодно целями.

1. Для `int` определена перегрузка вида `int ::operator<<(int val, size_t offset)`, выполняющая побитовый сдвиг влево. Аналогичные перегрузки есть для всех встроенных числовых типов данных.
2. `std::ostream` определяет свою перегрузку, `std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(T val)`, выполняющую вывод строкового представления `val` в поток. Да, именно строкового, поскольку единственная задача `istream` и `ostream` — форматированный ввод/вывод. Для всего остального есть `std::streambuf`.

Из всего вышесказанного можно сделать два вывода:

1. Смысл перегрузки и типы аргументов и возвращаемого значения компилятору неважны и оставляются на усмотрение программиста. Единственное, что фиксировано — имя функции (*`operator<<`*) и количество аргументов (*2*).
2. `operator<<` может быть не только функцией, но и методом класса. Тогда то, что находится слева от оператора, передаётся в качестве `this`.

Comment: Вообще-то в языке С++ проводится четкое качественное различие между *встроенными* операторами и *перегруженными* операторами. Они ведут себя очень по-разному. Никакой "перегрузки" оператора `<<` для выражения `5 << 3` нет и быть не может. В `5 << 3` используется именно *встроенный* оператор.